# is pkcs#7 suitable for signing and encrypting zip files?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature

I'm looking to protect zip files that I will be regularly sending to a 3rd party.

I need to ensure strong confidentiality and non-repudation.  I would like signing/encryption to be based on asymmetric keys to simplify key management.

Is PKCS#7 suitable for the use case described above?

Updated:

The zip file can be signed and the result can be encrypted using PKCS#7 Cryptographic Message Syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PKCS#7, now known as [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652), is a generic format for message with some content which is signed and/or encrypted. The content is *any sequence of bytes* so you can fit any kind of file in it, including Zip archives.

Of course CMS is just a tool. Using it won't magically sprinkle security everywhere. You will need to use it with some [public-key infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure) which will take care of distributing the public keys (as X.509 certificates). 95% of PKI is *management procedures*, not software.